# restart an app when Screen is OFF

Tags: android, screen, broadcastreceiver, alarm

My app is finishing when user touch the screen. For this, on onTouch() method I have

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FinActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

where FinActivity class is this one :

```
public class FinActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 1000),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

I want to restart my app when screen is OFF. I have this AlarmReceiver class :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            System.out.println("Screen OFF");
            wasScreenOn = false;

                Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            System.out.println("Screen ONN");
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }

}
```

but after 60 seconds I get NullPointerException at this line : `intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)`

Where is my mistake ? What i do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you check for null a `Intent` and ignore it?

Comment: it restart app without the if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to know whether your screen is turned on or off, you can use **PowerManager class** of android it is from **api level 1**.You can use **isScreenOn()** method for knowing status of screen.

You can get more details http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html here.